# Remove Window State and Close button from RadDock in Telerik Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have used Telerik RadDock in my windows application which is used to load the user control as docking window in my application. Now I need to remove window state and close button from docking window. Please suggest me a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Dim uc As UserControl1 = New UserControl1()

Me.RadDock1.DockControl(uc, DockPosition.Left)

uc.Show()

Comment: @Pro Grammer: It did not work. Defaulty RadDock has 3 buttons Window state,Auto Hide and Close button. I need to remove Window state and Close button from RadDock

Comment: Oh, I derped. I forgot what a docking window was. My bad

Comment: There is `ToolCaptionButtons` that can be set. I found the link [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-remove-the-close-button-from-a-raddock-documentwindow#N9xhu4OEPE2v3XdRQEJ_dw)

Comment: @Pro Grammer: It works fine but the problem is when i click the Auto Hide button it hides and when i click on the hided user control it opens and it is loaded with docked button. When it loads back i need with Auto Hide button

Comment: Can you not set the controls when it loads up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim window As HostWindow
  window = DirectCast(RadDock1.ActiveWindow, HostWindow)
  window.ToolCaptionButtons = ToolStripCaptionButtons.AutoHide
```

In ToolCaptionButtons option we can specify which button we want to have